# I want to create an S3 static web page that can only be accessed when connected to a VPN, but I configured the VPC endpoint and it has no effect

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I used a policy like this Endpoint policy is open mode

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowVPC",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::123-bucket/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:sourceVpce": [
                        "vpce-123",
                        "vpce-123"
                    ],
                    "aws:sourceVpc": "vpc-123"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The VPC terminal node has rules for routing to s3, but it does not seem to be effective. It is a Gateway type VPC terminal node.

I tried changing the bucket to public access but it didn't work. It still returned an error after I connected to the vpn and entered the vpc's IP.

## 403 Forbidden

- Code: AccessDenied
- Message: Access Denied

How can I solve it?

Comment: You only added a Deny in case of not using that specific endpoint, but didn't add Allo when using the endpoint.

Comment: {
  "Sid": "AccessToSpecificBucket",
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Principal": "*",
  "Action": [
     "s3:ListBucket",
     "s3:GetObject",
     "s3:PutObject"
  ],
  "Resource": [
     "arn:aws:s3:::bucket_name",
     "arn:aws:s3:::bucket_name/*"
  ]
}I re-added Allow in front of Deny but it still doesn’t work.

Comment: @Caldazar  now just like this  ,but not work~.~

Comment: Can you edit the question and put your policy there so it can be properly seen?

Comment: {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3::abc-bucket/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:sourceVpce": [
                        "vpce1234",
                        "vpce-12340"
                    ],
                    "aws:sourceVpc": "vpc-1234"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}

Comment: @Caldazar OK I updated the policy. Currently, it can be accessed from ec2 through the gateway type endpoint, but it does not matter whether the interface type is accessed from vpn.

Comment: I succeeded, the problem is that I did not enable private DNS, so the url should be in this format            https://bucket.vpce-XXXX.s3.【リージョン名】.vpce.amazonaws.com/【バケット名】/【オブジェクト名】